# After migrating from Swift 2, project fails to compile and computer hangs

Tags: ios, firebase, compilation, swift3, xcode8

I recently upgraded my project to Swift 3 (as a requirement by Xcode 8). Only SDKs I am using are Firebase and Facebook. Everything was working fine, until I migrated to Swift 3 and now it fails to build, i.e.: it gets stuck compiling swift source files. I've tried letting it compile and it went on for hours. My computer seemed to also be super laggy while it was compiling.

Anyone have similar issues and maybe solutions to this?

Comment: If you don't get any errors, it's still compiling. Check you task manager and you will see that it is processing the source files, which takes a lot of CPU power, so the "lag" is expected when compiling. If you change a major piece in your software like this, it has to recompile a lot of files, which can take a long time.

Comment: I don't think this is the case here considering this is a small project and there are only about 15 swift files

Comment: I get an error Command failed due to signal: Killed: 9